# GTM настройка событий добавления и удаления из избранного (e-com)

Tags: gtm

Есть сайт интернет-магазина, у каждой карточки товара есть кнопка добавления товара в избранное.
При каждом клике на эту кнопку в dataLayer отправляется одинаковое событие “add-to-wishlist” с массивом данных о товаре - то есть и при добавлении товара в избранное (первый клик), и при удалении из избранного (второй клик).

```
event: "add-to-wishlist",
cartItem: {
    id: "123345",
    price: "5000",
    name: "Example"
  }
```

**Можно ли как-то настроить теги в GTM так, чтобы при добавлении и удалении из избранного отправлялось 2 отдельных события?** (не меняя event)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дополнила описание